# How to run a batch script only on specfied sub folders within a root folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have a specific folder (mak) that has sub folders (1,2,3,4,5). I have a batch find and replace script that I want to run only on sub folders 1,2 and 3. How will this be possible ?

Comment: as you have a limited number of folders with known names what is the problem to enter each folder with `cd` and execute your command?

Comment: Well I tried that and the script breaks half way through, doesn't execute anymore. Anyways I found a solution with python. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ahmed, you should answer your own question and then accept that answer to mark your question answered. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a varribel system were you can tell the computer that these are the files i want serached then
throught that you can us cd C:...your main file location\%your varible1% and then have it loop so it will add each varible to another then set it up to create temp files so i knows which on has been made, look somthing like this

```
@echo off
Echo Max Numbers: 5
:setn
set /p n = 1
:start
 set /p V%n% = Enter File Path: 
:answer
set /p done = Is that all? (Y/N)
echo temp file > %done%.txt
if exist Y.txt goto File
if exist N.txt goto Varible%n%
goto answer
:varible1
echo %n%>%n%.txt
 if %n% = 1 set /p n = 2
goto start
:Varible2
echo %n%>%n%.txt
if %n% = 2 set /p n = 3
goto start
:Varible3 
echo %n%>%n%.txt
if %n% = 3 set /p n = 4
goto start
:Varible4
echo %n%>%n%.txt
if %n% = 4 set /p n = 5
goto start
:varible5
goto File
:file 
"Your file code here"
```

this code may not work it depends on the type of windows you have.